# Topology/Geometry book for self study

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on **topology and geometry** that is suited for self study. That means I would like it to include exercises and solutions.

Could you kindly recommend some literature?

Comment: For point-set topology with solutions, there is a good Schaum's Outlines book out there.

Comment: Well, if you're willing for forego solutions, Reid's *Geometry and Topology* is insightful.